# Have CSS hover style affect only hyperlinks

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, styles

When I [define styles for hyperlinks](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp), the "hover" style affects parts where the `<a>` tag is used only to define an ID, not a hyperlink, for example `<a id="a1">TEXT</a>`.

How can I get a hover style only for `<a>` tags **that contain a hyperlink**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an attribute selector…

```
a[href]:hover {

}
```

… or define hover states for linked and visited links:

```
a:link:hover,
a:visited:hover {

}
```

---

You could also *not use `a` elements for non-links*.

Since the introduction of HTML 4 in the mid-1990s, *any* element can be a link target so long as it has an id.

```
<section id="a1">
    <h2>TEXT</h2>
    <p>More content</p>
</section>
```